# $_FILES['myfile']['error'] is zero, but there's no file uploaded

Tags: php, macos

I'm trying to copy a production server onto an old Mac running 10.5. Everything works great, except uploading files.

Unfortunately, there are no errors being reported either by PHP or apache, just no file at the end. I've been setting permissions of everything I can find to 777, but no luck - even the simplest uploader tutorial produces a $_FILE['myfile']['error'] of zero, but when I look for the file listed in $_FILE['myfile']['tmp_name'] the file does not exist.

Any suggestions?

I've tried the built-in OSX versions of apache and PHP 5.2, and I've tried installing apache2 and PHP 5.3.4 from MacPorts. Both have the same results.

I figure this must be a permissions problem some place, but why don't I get an error?

Comment: Have you checked the upload dir in your PHP .ini file (/etc/php.ini)?

Comment: Yes. The directory exists, and has 777 permissions, and $_FILES[]['tmp_name'] is a fully qualified path to the correct directory.

Comment: Hmm. Are you using === to check the error code?

Comment: Have you tried print_r/var_dumping $_FILES?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the HTML of File Uploader.
Its FORM tag must contain

```
ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data"
```

To upload any file.

Comment: Actually, no, this was porting a working website from one hosting company to another. Turns out if the uploaded file is larger than the system's file limits, you get these results.